# accesing the value of properties using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I have an object and I want to write and xml element for each property in the object and the value as a string in the middle:

```
System.Type type = cabecera.GetType();
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] propiedades = type.GetProperties();

        xml.WriteStartDocument();
        xml.WriteStartElement("Factura");
            xml.WriteStartElement("CABFAC"); //inicio de cabecera

            // imprime inicio valor y fin de elemento por cada propiedad del objeto
            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propiedad in propiedades) 
            {
                xml.WriteStartElement(propiedad.Name); 
                xml.WriteString("value"); // here is the problem
                xml.WriteEndElement();
            }


            xml.WriteEndElement(); //fin de factura
        xml.WriteEndDocument();
        xml.Close();
```

How can I change the "value" for the propiedad.value x)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
xml.WriteString(propiedad.GetValue(cabecera, null).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

already solved ty men

xml.WriteStartElement(propiedad.Name);
                        object o = propiedad.GetValue(cabecera, null);
                        if (o!= null)
                            xml.WriteString(o.ToString().Trim());
                        xml.WriteEndElement();